# Anchor Boxes for Object detection

Tags: object-detection, yolov5

Can someone help me understand how are anchor boxes represented in YoloV5.
In the official code it is mentioned as:

- [10,13, 16,30, 33,23]  # P3/8
- [30,61, 62,45, 59,119]  # P4/16
- [116,90, 156,198, 373,326]  # P5/32

I understand that p3, p4 and p5 are layers of feature pyramids. But what are the numbers corresponding to. I'l appreciate if someone can clarify on:

1. What these number specify.
2. Their, significance.
3. Why are they changing from layer to layer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Anchor box is just a scale and aspect ratio of specific object classes in object detection. The FPN (Future Pyramid Network) has three outputs and each output's role is to detect objects according to their scale. For example:

- `P3/8` is for detecting **smaller** objects.
- `P4/16` is for detecting **medium** objects.
- `P5/32` is for detecting **bigger** objects.

So when you're going to detect `smaller` objects you need to use smaller anchor boxes and for **medium** objects you should use medium scale anchor boxes, so on. You can see it on following image as well:

[image]

You may have a question why bigger feature maps have smaller anchor boxes. It's because, during downsampling the feature maps if you downsample it many times you may lose smaller objects, that's why you should use **bigger** feature maps and **smaller** anchor boxes to detect **smaller** objects.